Trouble deploying MERN app to Azure, says app is running and waiting for my content. Not sure why it is not displaying my project
I have tried several times to deploy MERN project and I keep running into issues. First it would run locally but not on a server. Now that i've tried setting up with Azure it says my app is deployed and waiting for my content. But when I run it locally now nothing happens on submit and doesnt show existing database entries. Any help is appreciated.
Here is the link to the repo - https://github.com/zachmvm/IronWatchSecurity
I tried editing the yml file and that seemed to fix the errors uploading the app to Azure. But it still doesnt show up when I try to visit URL on Azure Web app.

there is a problem with the git URL it showing not found. can you tell the repository you are using in the git and also please share the code in the above question

please share the code in the above question. Please read How to Ask, along with how to create a minimal reproducible example.

how are you deploying? via a pipeline?

@Sampath the link should work now, sorry about that

@DerekGusoff its via Azure Web app services, I fixed the link to github

@Zach Whitsett please deploy the back-end and front-end code separately

Refer to so for the answer
